# Неправильное вычисление недели через datepart(week, ...)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Сделал в своей таблице авто-вычесление недели из даты, как пример имеем дату `2021-01-08 00:00:00.000` и хотим получить из нее неделю `(datepart(week,[Наша_Дата]))`.

В моем примере 8 Января 2021 года, это первая неделя в году. SQL показывает мне, что это вторая неделя .

В чем проблема и как ее решить?

---

Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Попробуйте указать “iso_week” вместо “week”

Comment: @MaxU это сработало. Большое спасибо. Только вот в чем сообственно разница?

Comment: Первая неделя и первая ПОЛНАЯ неделя - это не одно и то же...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В старых версиях SQL Server разработчики не сильно заботились об ISO стандартах и решили считать неделю содержащую «1 января» первой.

По ISO стандартам первой считается неделя, на которую приходится «4 января». В более поздних версиях это учли и добавили модификатор “iso_week”. Модификатор “week” оставили неизменным из соображений совместимости.

[Из Википедии](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> The first week of the year, hence, always contains 4 January. ISO week
> year numbering therefore slightly deviates from the Gregorian for some
> days close to 1 January.

Comment: первая неделя с 4го января еще больше, кажется запутывает ситуацию :D

Comment: @teran, не «с 4го», а та, на которую выпадает 4е января. Это не я придумал - это ISO стандарт. Там есть ещё три формулировки, но мне эта показалась наиболее запоминающейся